# Jquery BMI Calculator Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am trying to make a BMI calculator and I cannot get the BMI number or the Message output into their boxes. I know I'm either missing something or something else is wrong so hopefully you can help. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BMI Calculator</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bmi.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
        <form id="bmi">
            What is your weight (lbs)?
                <input class="calculations" type="text" name="weight" size="10" max="4"><br>
            What is your height (in)?
                <input class="calculations" type="text" name="height" size="10"><br>

            <input type="submit" id="calculateBMI" name="verify" value="Calculate BMI">
            <p>Your BMI:
                <input class="calculations" type="text" id="dopeBMI" size="10">
                <br>This Means:
                <input class="calculations" type="text" id="meaning" size="25">
            </p>
        </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("bmi").click(function() {
        var weight = $("weight").value;
        var height = $("height").value;
        if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
            var finalBmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703;
            $("dopeBMI") = finalBmi;
            if (finalBmi < 18.5) {
                $("meaning").value = "You are underweight.";
            }
            if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 24.9) {
                $("meaning").value = "You are normal.";
            }
            if (finalBmi > 24.9 && finalBmi < 29.99) {
                $("meaning").value = "You are overweight.";
            }
        } else {
            $("meaning").value = "You are obese.";
            }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the SO community and it seems you are new to the jquery, hence I would like you to highlight missing points in your code, so that you can learn :)

1) Javascript code should be included within the body under "script" tag

2) Study more about jquery selectors - To select an element by id, use # - $("#bmi")

3) As it's form use the submit function instead of click.

4) e.preventDefault() to prevent the default behavior of form submission

5) Select element by name or any attribute - $("[name='weight']")

6) To get the value of input element, use val() function

7) To set the value to an input element use the same val("what ever the value")

Complete working example can be found here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bmi").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var weight = $("[name='weight']").val();
   var height = $("[name='height']").val();
   if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
    var finalBmi = (weight / (height * height)) * 703;
    $("#dopeBMI").val(finalBmi);
    if (finalBmi < 18.5) {
     $("#meaning").val("You are underweight.");
    }
    if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 24.9) {
     $("#meaning").val("You are normal.");
    }
    if (finalBmi > 24.9 && finalBmi < 29.99) {
     $("#meaning").val("You are overweight.");
    }
   } else {
    $("#meaning").val("You are obese.");
    }   
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <center>
        <form id="bmi">
            What is your weight (lbs)?
                <input class="calculations" type="text" name="weight" size="10" max="4"><br>
            What is your height (in)?
                <input class="calculations" type="text" name="height" size="10"><br>

            <input type="submit" id="calculateBMI" name="verify" value="Calculate BMI">
            <p>Your BMI:
                <input class="calculations" type="text" id="dopeBMI" size="10" readonly>
                <br>This Means:
                <input class="calculations" type="text" id="meaning" size="25" readonly>
            </p>
        </form>
        </center>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am new to jquery and have been trying my best to learn it but still fail to do simple things I learned a bit ago. I went through your points to see what I was missing and where and I feel like I have a better understanding of what I was doing wrong, thank you!